# Is this data stationary ? I’m having issues with the correlogram

Tags: stationarity, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller, acf-pacf

I have run the augmented dickey fuller test and the NGperron test , I have taken the first difference ,the data seems stationary however the correlogram is still exactly the same and the values as before I even ran those tests . Why is that ? How can I fix this ? The data are within the bounds however the first p values are above 0.05 and then they are all 0. Is this stationary? I don’t know how else to make the data stationary and to see the correct correlogram after all these tests [image]

Comment: Could you explain what "taken 1 lag" means and how you know the correlogram has not changed?  (Many correlograms are drawn at such tiny scales that it's impossible to detect anything but large differences among them: you have redraw them or otherwise inspect their values.)

Comment: I have taken the first difference of both the NG Perron , the ADF test and the values of the correlogram are Exactly the same. The first 5 pvalues are larger than 0 but then the rest are all 0 and i don’t know if this indicates stationarity. All data in the correlogram are within the bounds